# is there a php function that returns an assoc array from

Tags: php, arrays, query-string

I would like to convert the current querystring ( or any key/value pair based strng ) into an assoc array.

is there a php function that does that already?

```
$my_var  = "age=45&name=john";
$my_ary = explode_into_an_assoc_array("&",$my_var)

//and now I can go as

echo $my_ary['name'] prints john
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

parse_str($str, $arr);
from 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php

i.e.

```
<?php
$my_var  = "age=45&name=john";
$arr = Array();
parse_str($my_var, $arr);
print_r($arr);
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

[parse_str](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) is the function you need:

```
$my_var  = 'age=45&name=john';
parse_str($my_var, $my_ary);

echo $my_ary['name']; // john
echo $my_ary['age']; // 45
```

> I would like to convert the current querystring [...]

The current query string will automatically be parsed by PHP and be available as `$_GET['name']`, `$_GET['age']`

Comment: parse_str does not return an array. I guess such a function does not exist as @Neal pointed out.

Comment: From the OP: *I would like to convert the current querystring ( or any key/value pair based strng ) **into an assoc array***. `parse_str` definitely does that. Either way, your particular parsing of the question borders on pedantic and is certainly not worthy of a downvote.

Comment: @JohnSmith Read the linked documentation and refer to the example.  It does not return an array, but if you include an array as the second parameter it will store the results in that array.

Comment: Yes. I re-read the parse_str manual. I had missed the second arg that makes it do what I wanted to do, when I read it for the first time. Thank you.

Comment: Gah, I hate it when the first correct answer misses the accept. +1 for you sir

Answer (score 4):

[parse_str](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) is what you want i think.